# Get Prevous/Next Post Specific Category Without Excludes

Tags: categories, next-post-link

Is it possible to mimic the get_next_post / get_previous_post WP functions without using the $in_same_term boolean / $excluded_terms array pattern?

I have a site with many overlapping categories that would like to navigate on specific ones.

For example, I have Post with {A, B, C}. I want to navigate to Post 2 {A, C, D} against Category A. If I exclude {C} this one won't fly though. I simply want to get the next/previous post that shares a category I specify. Any ideas?

I can't blacklist specific categories in the [Get Adjacant Post filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_adjacent_post_where/) either.